# Does Content Security Policy block bookmarklets?

Tags: javascript, security, firefox, mozilla, content-security-policy

Does Mozillas [CSP](http://www.bitstampede.com/2010/10/10/content-security-policy-documentation-in-progress/) block to execute [Javascript from a bookmark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet) by default?

Can it be configured to do so?

Comment: Just curiosity, why would you want to disable bookmarklets?

Comment: I don't I just worried some one else might do that because they do not want to have Javascript injected on there webpage.

Comment: There are always things like greasemonkey. If the **user** decides that he wants to inject javascript in the website that will only affect himself it's nobody's right to prevent him from doing it.

Comment: Greasemonkey will have the same problem. They maybe able to rewrite the http header or change the browser settings.

Comment: I'm sure GM will not. It's a browser extension so it's generally immune to security restrictions - and scripts don't directly execute in the site's context.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As of 2017, the answer is still a definitive "maybe" - just like when this answer was originally posted in 2011. The [specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSP3/#extensions) clearly says:

> Policy enforced on a resource SHOULD NOT interfere with the operation of user-agent features like addons, extensions, or bookmarklets.

And this is indeed the behavior I see in Chrome 61: a bookmarklet will run on https://addons.mozilla.org/, a site that has a strict content security policy without `script-src: 'unsafe-inline'`. Yet in Firefox 56 bookmarklets won't run on this website and a CSP violation is being reported.

There is a very long discussion on this issue in the [Firefox bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=866522), in particular linking to a [similar discussion on the W3C spec](https://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=23357). So as of now, you cannot really rely on bookmarklets being unaffected by CSP. You can always disable CSP altogether, but that's one important protection layer less for you.

Comment: Thanks for testing this! BUT you can simply switch of CSP if you want. Open about:config and set "security.csp.enable" to "false". So you will be able to run you own booklets anyway.

Comment: @PiTheNumber: My answer already says that you can switch off CSP - and advises not to do so.

Comment: Sorry, I did not saw you edit when I was writing the comment.

Answer (score 5):

The behavior is specified in mozillas wiki.

> CSP should not interfere with the operation of user-supplied scripts (such as browser add-ons and bookmarklets).

Have a look here:
https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/CSP/Specification#Non-Normative_Client-Side_Considerations

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the CSP blocks bookmarklets in Mozilla Firefox. There is a [bug about it](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=866522).

However, you can get around this restriction by injecting the JS code into an external CSS stylesheet, like my [Top News Feed bookmarklet](https://niutech.github.io/topnewsfeed/) does:

External CSS:

```
#topnewsfeed { font-family: '(function(){/*payload*/})()'; }
```

Bookmarklet JS:

```
(function() {
    var a = document.createElement("link");
    a.rel = "stylesheet";
    a.href = "//niutech.github.io/topnewsfeed/topnewsfeed.css";
    a.onload = function() {
        var a = b.currentStyle ? b.currentStyle.fontFamily : document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(b, null).fontFamily;
        eval(a.replace(/^["']|\\|["']$/g, ""));
    };
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    var b = document.createElement("div");
    b.id = "topnewsfeed";
    document.body.appendChild(b);
})()
```

The bookmarklet loads a CSS file containing JS code, adds an element styled by this CSS, reads the element style attribute and `eval` the code.

Comment: `Refused to load the stylesheet 'https://<mysite.com>/bookmarklet.css' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' assets-cdn.github.com".`

Answer (score 0):

I have created a work-around "fix" for this issue using a Greasemonkey userscript (in Firefox). You can now have bookmarklets on all CSP and https:// sites, plus have your bookmarklets in a nice, easily-editable library file instead of being individually squished into a bookmark.

See: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/greasemonkey-users/mw61Ynw5ORc/Gl_BNUhtSq0J

Comment: This method not work because the bookmarklet can't be executed (bookmarklet = `unsafe-inline`)